# Limit of sequence to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> For a sequence $\{a_n\}$, given that the value of $$\sum^{\infty}_{n\ =\ 1} (a{_n}{^2}+4na_n+4n^2) = 4$$
>   what is the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{n}}$$

Only thing I get from this question is that the given equation can be expressed as a quadratic function and I have no idea how to approach this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If a series converges, the terms of the series converge to $0$. What is the term of the convergent series here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n^2+4na_n+4n^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+2n)^2.
$$
So as the series converges, then necessarily $(a_n+2n)^2\to 0$, and thus $\frac{a_n+2n}{n}\to 0$, also.
Hence
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}\to -2.
$$